# Output not rendering using a method

Tags: methods, vuejs2

Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
<span>{{ getGenres(movie.genre_ids) }}</span>
```

should output:

```
Action, Adventure, ..etc
```

I've got a JSON file which contains the following structure:

```
[
  {
       "id": 28,
       "name": "Action"
  },
  {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Adventure"
  }
]
```

Here is my method:

```
getGenres(genre_ids) {
    Movies.getGenres(genre_ids);
}
```

Movies.js contains the method is calling to, which is:

```
getGenres(genre_ids) {
    let genres_array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < genre_ids.length; i++) {
        let matching_genre = genres.filter(genre => genre.id === genre_ids[i]);
        genres_array.push(matching_genre[0].name);
    }
    return genres_array;
}
```

The issue here is that it doesn't output the names, but if I console.log(genres_array); it does work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It can be a problem with how the array of ids is populated. Maybe the way the values are set in the array makes it impossible for Vue to detect the changes, and it doesn't pass new values to `movie` method. You can check the [reactivity guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in Vue docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find return here

```
getGenres(genre_ids) {
    Movies.getGenres(genre_ids);
}
```

I trust it should be like this

```
getGenres(genre_ids) {
    return Movies.getGenres(genre_ids).join(', ');
}
```